# I pass a string -> NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am writing a ADnroid app, and when i pass a string at this point, I get a nullpointer ...Does someone know why?

**Code**

```
        Elements titles = doc.select("h3 a");
        String[] titlelist = null;
        Bitmap[] bitmaps = null;
        outputText = "";
        int i = 0;
        for (Element title : titles) {
            titlelist[i] = title.text(); // <--- here comes the NullPointer
            i = i + 1;
        }
```

**Log:**

```
08-18 17:17:54.522  26470-26470/de.m4lik.somesampleapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.m4lik.somesampleapp, PID: 26470
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.m4lik.somesampleapp.MainActivity$TheTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:95)
        at de.m4lik.somesampleapp.MainActivity$TheTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        ...
```

The doc.select part is jsoup code where i select headings from a website.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: a proper IDE shouldn't allow you to even compile this, or at the very least give you a warning. (also, I don't understand why you explicitly set the list to `null`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`titlelist` is not initialized.

You need to initialize it prior to assigning Strings to it :

```
String[] titlelist = new String[titles.size()]; // assuming Elements has a size() method
```

Comment: thx, worked with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your `titlelist array`, therefore referencing an element of that `array` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Initialize it with:

```
String[] titlelist = new String[titles.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `titlelist` is defined with a `null` value. Accessing an element with

```
titlelist[i]
```

is therefore producing the NPE. As you are only setting the array elements you probably wanted to declare this variable as

```
int length = calculateLength(titles); // you must implement this method yourself
String[] titlelist = new String[length];
```